# Performing a MERGE INSERT on unmatched columns returns zero rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert the instructor IDs of the team chiefs that went on missions into another table. The `TEAM_CHIEF` column of the `MISSIONS` table is text for the instructor name, so I have to insert them based on a `LIKE` clause of the `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` in the `INSTRUCTORS` table. I have a unique constraint for the `MISSION_TEAM` table on columns `MISSION_ID` and `INSTRUCTOR_ID` combined to validate no duplicate rows on those two columns, hence I am using a MERGE WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT query. Here is my query so far:

```
MERGE INTO DDMS.MISSION_TEAM mt
USING(
    SELECT m.MISSION_ID AS mi, i.INSTRUCTOR_ID AS ii, 5603 AS pi FROM DDMS.MISSIONS m
    JOIN DDMS.MISSION_TEAM mt2
    ON m.MISSION_ID = mt2.MISSION_ID
    JOIN DDMS.INSTRUCTORS i
    ON mt2.INSTRUCTOR_ID = i.INSTRUCTOR_ID 
    WHERE CONCAT(i.FIRST_NAME, i.LAST_NAME) LIKE ('%' || m.TEAM_CHIEF || '%')
) t ON (mt.MISSION_ID = t.mi) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (MISSION_ID, INSTRUCTOR_ID, POSITION_ID)
    VALUES (t.mi, t.ii, t.pi);
```

My SELECT query **does** return records; 134 of them as a matter of fact. But when attempting the MERGE query, 0 rows are returned. The critical line is this one:

```
ON (mt.MISSION_ID = t.mi)
```

My primary key for the `MISSION_TEAM` table is `MISSION_TEAM_ID`. I'm not sure how I'd match that with a column of table `t` in the `ON` clause. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: All 134 rows must already have a matching row in `mt` because of `ON m.MISSION_ID = mt2.MISSION_ID`; so will be none that hit `WHEN NOT MATCHED`. And if they did then the insert would fail because you haven't supplied a PK value. Are you really trying to insert, or actually to update a *matched* row - maybe with a filter to avoid your secondary duplicate issue? Including sample data (or a [mcve]) and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: @AlexPoole The `MISSION_TEAM` table actually already contains some `INSTRUCTOR_ID` values - to give a little backstory, this data was imported from Access, all with poor modeling/normalization such that the team chiefs exist in two different tables. So I want to make sure I don't duplicate a `MISSION_ID` and `INSTRUCTOR_ID` on the data transfer - and no, I don't want to update, just insert. Basically, I want to insert a row if the duo of `MISSION_ID` and `INSTRUCTOR_ID` does not already exist in another row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative using an `INSERT INTO SELECT` query instead of `MERGE`. In order to avoid inserting duplicate pairs of `MISSION_ID` and `INSTRUCTOR_ID` into the `MISSION_TEAM` table, I performed a `NOT IN` clause combining the two columns (which behaves differently than doing two separate `WHERE NOT IN` clauses). Here is my final query:

```
INSERT INTO DDMS.MISSION_TEAM (MISSION_ID, INSTRUCTOR_ID, POSITION_ID)
SELECT m.MISSION_ID, i.INSTRUCTOR_ID, 5603 
FROM DDMS.MISSIONS m
LEFT JOIN DDMS.INSTRUCTORS i
ON m.TEAM_CHIEF LIKE ('%' || CONCAT(CONCAT(i.FIRST_NAME, ' '), i.LAST_NAME) || '%')
WHERE i.INSTRUCTOR_ID IS NOT NULL
AND (m.MISSION_ID, i.INSTRUCTOR_ID) NOT IN
(SELECT MISSION_ID, INSTRUCTOR_ID FROM DDMS.MISSION_TEAM);
```

Notice I also had to change the logic on the text of the `TEAM_CHIEF` being similar in pattern (`LIKE`) to the concatenated `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` from the `INSTRUCTORS` table; instead of putting it in a `WHERE` clause, I put it in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`. The query without the `NOT IN` clause returned 86 records, whereas with the `NOT IN` clause returned 60 records. That means 60 records were inserted, while 26 would have had the same `MISSION_ID` and `INSTRUCTOR_ID`. An update would not have been necessary for those 26 since the same data already existed for them.

I will still accept answers using the `MERGE` query if anyone is game for it; it would be a nice learning experience for me since I'm a little unfamiliar with it.